# Why multiple HCL languages

Tags: chisel, myhdl

I understand that Chisel is a HDL/HCL language to overcome some of Verilog/SystemVerilog restrictions by using higher abstraction level.
And it is open source as well.

It might be a bit naive and presumptuous, but still I would like to ask.

My question is that why do so many similar efforts are working in parallel, e.g. Blusspec, spinalHDL, Pyha etc?

I mean, is there any reason why the development community may not choose one of these and concentrate efforts on stabilizing or enhancing one of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what is happening now, it just takes a while to choose.
Although the past does not show that the best technology wins, let us hope it does this time.